# Python permanent assignment variables

Tags: python, list, reference

I have just started python and came across something kind of strange.

The following code assigns a co-ordinate of x=1 and y=2 to the variable test. The test2 variable assigns itself the same value as test and then the [x] value for test2 is changed to the old [x] value minus 1. This works fine, however, when the last part is executed, not only does it minus 1 from the [x] value in test2, it does the same to the [x] value in the test variable too.

```
test = [1,2];
test2 = test;
test2[1] = test2[1] - 1;
```

I found doing the following worked fine but I still don't understand why the first method changes the test value as well as the test2 value.

```
test = [1,2];
test2 = test;
test2 = [test2[0] -1 ,test2[1]];
```

Could someone please explain why this happens.

Thank You
TheLorax

Comment: This `test2[1] = test2[1] - 1;` does not match your description. `test2[1]` is the _y_ value for the array; the _x_ value would be `test2[0]`.

Comment: Pro tip: In Python the semicolons are unnecessary and it is convention to omit them. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, like in Java, *assignment* per se never makes a copy -- rahter, assignment adds another *reference* to the same object as the right-hand side of the `=`.  (Argument passing works the same way).  Strange that you've never heard of the concept, when Python is quite popular and Java even much more so (and many other languages *tend* to work similarly, possibly with more complications or distinguos).

When you *want* a copy, you *ask* for a copy (as part of the expression that is on the right-hand side, or gets used to get the argument you're passing)!  In Python, depending on your exact purposes, there are several ways -- the `copy` module of the standard library being a popular ones (with functions `copy`, for "shallow" copies, and `deepcopy` -- for "deep" copies, of course, i.e., ones where, not just the container, but every contained item, also gets deep copied recursively).

Often, though, what you want is "a new list" -- whether the original sequence is a list, a copy, or something else that's iterable, you may not care: you want a new `list` instance, whose items are the same as those of "something else".  The perfect way to express this is to use `list(somethingelse)` -- call the `list` type, which always makes a new instance of list, and give it as an argument the iterable whose items you want in the new list.  Similarly, `dict(somemapping)` makes a new `dict`, and `set(someiterable)` makes a new set -- calling a type to make a new instance of that type is a very general and useful concept!

Comment: But what about: `a = 5`, `b = a`, `a = 6`, `assert(b==6)` - assertion failure? This doesn't make a reference; seems like a copy to me?

Comment: Again, this is due to name binding rather than assignment semantics.

When you say "b = a", you are bind the name "b" to the object that is bound to "a", i.e. 5. Then when you say "a = 6", you are (re-)binding the name "a" to the object "6", but the name "b" remains bound to "5".

Comment: Assignment is a form of name binding (others name-binding statements are `def`, `class`, `import`, `form`, `with` and `except` with `as` clauses, ...).  Re-binding a barename (i.e., binding a barename that was previously bound to something else) never affects whatever object that name was previously bound to (nor what is or isn't bound to other names).  Calling a **mutating method** is of course a completely different matter; quite different, too, are "variants" of assignment that are enriched by operators (`+=` &c), or affect attributes of an object or items in a container.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you do `test2 = test` you are not copying the contents of the list, but simply assigning `test2` a reference to the original list. Thus, any changes to the `test2` will also affect `test`.

The right way to do this is using [`deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) from the copy module (or `copy()` if you can get away with a shallow copy.

```
import copy
test2 = copy.deepcopy(test) # deep copy

test2 = copy.copy(test)) # shallow copy

test2 = test[:] # shallow copy using slices
```

See [this page](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list) for a more in-depth explanation as well as other methods to copy a list.

Comment: Hi Ailyn, Thank You for your reply. This is the first time I have seen this in any language. Is there a way to just copy the contents without linking them in any way? Thanks TheLorax

Comment: @The_Lorax In fact, a lot of languages behave this way. The most obvious one that always uses copies instead is PHP.

Comment: For this kind of example, test2=test[:] would be sufficient. But for lists within lists, or other nasty structures, deepcopy is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

`[1,2]` is an array and when you assign it to `test` you assign a reference to that array to test. So when you do `test2=test`, you are assigning the reference to yet another variable. Make changes to any variable and the array will get changed.

Your second example works, because you create a new array altogether. You might as well have done it like this:

```
test = [1,2]
test2 = [test[0]-1, test[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not do assignment.

It does name binding.

There is a difference, and it is explained wonderfully and in detail [here](http://www.python.net/crew/mwh/hacks/objectthink.html).

In your first example:
Your first line binds the name "test" to a list object created by the  "[1,2]" expression.
Your second line binds the name "test2" to the *same* object that is bounded to "test".
Your third line mutates the object bound to "test2", which is the same as the object bound to by "test".

In your second example: 
Your first line binds the name "test" to a list object created by the  "[1,2]" expression.
Your second line binds the name "test2" to the *same object* that is bounded to "test".
Your third line binds the name "test2" to a *new* object, created by the expression "[test2[0]-1, test2[1](http://www.python.net/crew/mwh/hacks/objectthink.html)]".

If you really want two independent lists with the same values bound to different variables, you need to:

```
>>> test = [1, 2]
>>> test2 = list(test)
>>> test2[0] = 3
>>> print(test)
[1, 2]
>>> print(test2)
[3, 2]
```

Note that this is a shallow-copy list, so changing the state of the object of an element in `test2` will, of course, effect `test` if the the same object is found in that list.

p.s. Python. Semi-colons. Ugly. Unnecessary. Do not use.